# OneSignal returns invalid identifier_auth_hash

Tags: python, openssl, onesignal

OneSignal returns an error when I use AuthHash in the way we have in official documentation [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/identity-verification#sdk-setemail-methods) I'm using this code:

```
import base64
one_signal_auth_key = hmac.new('onesignal_rest_api_key'.encode(), email.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
one_signal_auth_key = one_signal_auth_key.digest()
one_signal_auth_key = base64.b64encode(one_signal_auth_key).decode()
```

Key generated by this code is equal to `openssl` result:

```
echo -n "someemail@email.com" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "API_KEY" -binary | openssl enc -base64 -A
```

What do I do wrong?